# How to call javascript from backingbean jsf

Tags: javascript, jsf

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.GetType(),
    "ReturnScript", 
    "<script language='javascript'> alert('" + ErrorMsg + "');</script>");
```

alternate in java (JSF)

Comment: Either I haven't had enough coffee yet, or this is a banner day for vague, unintelligible questions.

Comment: @Pointy: this code sample comes from ASP.NET world. He's asking for a JSF equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

Just print the JS code as-is in the JSF view. The JS runs at client machine, not at server machine. You can use `<h:outputText>` for this.

```
<h:outputText value="<script>alert('foo');</script>" escape="false" />
```

You can even get it as a bean property:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.script}" escape="false" />
```

The `escape="false"` is there to prevent the (default) HTML-escaping of the value.

**See also:**

- [Communication between Java/JSP/JSF and JavaScript](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html)

Comment: Hi I have applied your solution. In my case its showing this error - Error Parsing /viewMetadata/DynamicCss.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 28] The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.

Comment: @Kush: that will indeed happen if you're using Facelets instead of JSP. Just manually escape it. See also e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883860/how-to-insert-special-characters-like-and-into-jsf-components-value-attribu/6883872#6883872