# How to insert special characters like & and < into JSF components' value attribute?

Tags: jsf, xhtml, facelets

How to insert special characters like `&` and `<` into JSF components `value` attribute ?

For example: I want something like this:

```
<h:outputText value="Tom & Jerry Show" />
```

When I try this, I get the following exception:

> javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /foo.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 15] The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

And in case of `<`, I get the following exception:

> javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /foo.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 15] The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "h:outputText" must not contain the '<' character.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You need to escape them to [XML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

```
<h:outputText value="Tom &amp; Jerry Show" />
```

This problem is not related to JSF per se, but to the view technology. You're apparently using Facelets (which is perfectly fine!). Facelets is however a XML based view technology, so you would need to ensure that the template is well formed XML and that all special characters which are to be represented as-is, are been escaped like above.

In the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) you can find a list of predefinied character entities which *needs* to be escaped in the XML whenever you'd like to display them as-is. It are the following character entities:

```
"     &quot;
&     &amp;
'     &apos;
<     &lt;
>     &gt;
```

#### See also:

- [The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303779/the-entity-name-must-immediately-follow-the-in-the-entity-reference)

Comment: thanks!!! i'm switching between rails and legacy jsf/j2ee development and this completely slipped my mind. thanks for the reminder!

Comment: great answer, as usual, but what about if I need to render a special character like a vowel with an accent mark? (so common in my language!!). Usually I'd do: `&aacute;` which renders `á`. Please how can I achieve this in JSF, in both: plain text scenarios and, for example, an `h:link`'s `value` attribute?. Thanx

Comment: @Scaramouche: Just type the `á` right away in the file and save it. We're not in 1990 anymore. You can safely save files as UTF-8 (as long as your editor is correctly configured to do so). XML uses already by default UTF-8. XML entities are only needed for XML-special characters such as the five listed in the answer, not for others.