# How to ignore imported external javascript in JSF

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2, facelets

I have an xhtml page loading an external javascript by using `<script src="<external url>" type="text/javascript" ></script>`

Is there a way to make JSF not care about the output of the script? I'd like to know this because the JSF SAXCompiler is throwing exceptions because of it:

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /pages/index.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 53] The reference to entity "c" must end with the ';' delimiter.
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:421)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doMetadataCompile(SAXCompiler.java:404)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler.metadataCompile(Compiler.java:130)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:326)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.access$200(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:92)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:165)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:163)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:94)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:89)
at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:99)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:114)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:143)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:62)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:259)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:208)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewMetadataImpl.createMetadataView(ViewMetadataImpl.java:113)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:233)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: Just asking, does the exception happen if you remove the script tag too? Maybe the problem is not with the script itself but with the url it references. Can you also post the true script importing line?

Comment: It was already in my comment on Balus C's reply but here is the import line: Line 53 is my javascript import: `<script src="http://view.light-speed.com/mumble.php?url=https%3A//api.mumble.com/mumble/‌​cvp.php%3Ftoken%3DLSG-6D-ECBDEB&c=000000&r=0&h=450&w=160&css=https%3A//view.light‌​-speed.com/styles/mumble-minimal.css"`

Comment: I see, still there was no reply yet when I asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the problem. You seem to think that the script is included by JSF in the webserver. This is not true. The script is individually downloaded by the webbrowser during parsing the retrieved JSF-generated HTML code.

If you need more detailed assistance to fix the real problem, then you'd need to show line 53 of `/pages/index.xhtml`. The exception at least suggests that you're using somewhere `&c` without escaping the ampersand. E.g.

```html
<p>Bla bla &c bla bla</p>
```

Facelets is a XML based view technology, you need to [escape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) XML special characters `&`, `<`, `>` and `"`.

```html
<p>Bla bla &amp;c bla bla</p>
```

#### See also:

- [How to insert special characters like & and < into JSF components' value attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883860/how-to-insert-special-characters-like-and-into-jsf-components-value-attribu/6883872#6883872)

Comment: Line 53 is my javascript import: `<script src="http://view.light-speed.com/mumble.php?url=https%3A//api.mumble.com/mumble/cvp.php%3Ftoken%3DLSG-6D-ECBDEB&c=000000&r=0&h=450&w=160&css=https%3A//view.light-speed.com/styles/mumble-minimal.css" type="text/javascript" ></script>
`

Comment: As answered, just replace all occurrences of `&` in XML by `&amp;` and you're fine.

Comment: I don't understand how I could have missed that one & that's in the URL... Let me try to HTML entity that one and see what happens...

Comment: Ok sorry for wasting all of your time because this one was actually very obvious! Must have been too late on too many occasions.