# How to escape characters on primefaces p:submenu label

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my website I have a p:menu with multiple `p:submenu`, one of them has on its label a special character (&). I've already tried encoding the characters `&amp;` and `&#38;` , but without success. I did also override the label with a facet, but  the label wasn't rendered by the browser:

```
<f:facet name="label">
     <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{lang['megamenu.phoneandmessaging']}"/>
</f:facet>
```

To finalize, the `p:submenu` nor `p:menu` doesn't have any option to escape the characters, e.g `escape="false"`.

This is a snippet of my menu:

```
<p:menu expanded="true">
     <p:submenu label="{lang['megamenu.phoneandmessaging']}"
                            expanded="true"> 
                    .....                           

      </p:submenu>
</p:menu>
```

Comment: `<p:submenu label="&amp;Test" expanded="true">` works fine for me.  As a test you might want to try setting the label directly.  Are you sure you are encoding correctly all the [special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6883872/1980659)?