# jquery DragDrop calling BackingBean function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsf-2, backing-beans

I have a little script for drag&drop a table and it's working fine. But I've a problem: I have to pass the start/endPosition to my BackingBean. Is there a way to call a BackingBean function from jquery (with parameters)? Or do you know some nice workaround?

Code for drag&drop:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var startPosition;
    var endPosition;
    $('#table tbody').sortable({
    cursor: "move",
    start:function(event, ui){
      startPosition = ui.item.prevAll().length;
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
      endPosition = ui.item.prevAll().length;

      // Call BackingBean function

     }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BackingBean is Server Side, what you could do is make a call to a javascript function in you backingbean code, and of course changing your function to return both the start and end position.

Comment: How is that exactly working? Do you have an example code for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061775/how-to-call-javascript-from-backingbean-jsf

Comment: I think BalusC's code is really helpful here (http://balusc.blogspot.co.at/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html#PassVariablesFromClientSideToServerSide). I'll give it a try.

Comment: I solved it with BalusC's example. Thank you for your answer and thanks to @BalusC.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two hidden input fields in your xhtml page like

```
  <h:inputHidden id="input1" value="#{bean.startPosition}" /> // getters and setters for startPosition in your bean
  <h:inputHidden id="input2" value="#{bean.endPosition}" />
```

and set the values which your are getting from the above Jquery Script to these fields

```
   document.getElementById('form:input1').value=startPosition;
   document.getElementById('form:input2').value=endPosition;
```

and get them in the bean.It should do your job.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I already did that with BalusC's code (http://balusc.blogspot.co.at/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html#PassVariablesFromClientSideToServerSide). I made a new form, which I hide in my jquery code ($('form').hide()).