# Calling javascript based on return value of action controller method in JSF?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

I have written an action method in backing bean which is invoked by action attribute of command button. On successful execution it returns 'null' otherwise it returns 'error'. What I need to is, I want to display an appropriate message in javascript dialog box based on return value of action method. Can anyone please tell me how to achieve that?

Comment: you can update some hidden filed in you page and check its value on `success` of your `f:ajax`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using JSF 2 you can use some `<f:ajax/>` magic here. Nest one of this tags inside your command button:

```
<h:commandButton id="yourCmdButton" action="#{yourBean.yourMethod}">
    <f:ajax render="hiddenComponent" onevent="displayMessage">
</h:commandButton>
```

`yourMethod` should update the value you mention to a field that's bound to an `<h:inputHidden/>` with `id="hiddenComponent"` and, through ajax, the component will be updated. Then after that, the `displayMessage` javascript function will be called (`onevent` defines a callback javascript function for the associated jax request) and there you will have to fetch the value of that component and display a message if necessary.

On the other hand, you can make use of the so called *Flash Scope*, tough it isn't a scope per se. It can be accessed in different ways either by injecting it into the bean:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{flash}")
private Flash flash;

//The setter is required
public void setFlash(Flash newFLash) {
    flash = newFlash;
}
```

or by obtaining it directly:

```
Flash jsfFlash = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash();
jsfFlash.put("errorMsg", "error");
//Or jsfFlash.put("errorMsg", null) if there's no error.
```

The Flash is a `Map` that allows the survival of a parameter one step ahead of a request, allowing the native implementation of a POST - Redirect - GET pattern without almost no effort on your part.

On the page, you can access the flash directly and render a message if the flash doesn't contain the error attribute:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{flash.errorMsg != null}">
    <p>
        Well... it seems an error occured...
    </p>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Remember that, should your flash key string include a period for some reason, you'll have to use this nomenclature instead:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{flash['error.message'] != null}">
```

Just remember to rerender a parent `<h:panelGroup/>` for that component (through the use of the `<f:ajax/>` tag without an `onevent` javascript callback function). About rerendering the parent, you can't rerender a conditionally rendered component directly in JSF, so you'll end up with something like this:

```
<h:panelGroup id="messageParentGroup">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{flash.errorMsg}">
        ...

<h:commandButton ...>
    <f:ajax render="messageParentGroup"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Also, take into account the context of the components. You might have to define a full path for that component and not a relative one.

As a side note, why aren't you using JSF's validation? Either by using a validator method or a fully implemented validator alongside an `<h:messages/>` component would be better and you avoid the contamination of your form values (since the validator kicks in and prevents the SetValues among other Phases from happening).

Comment: Thank you :) I'll try using ajax.

Comment: @user2235057 If you find any issue you know where to find me :)

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("myfunction()")` method inside your backing bean. It lets you execute client side javascript code. Unfortunately this is only available (afaik) in Primefaces.

Comment: but I m not using Primefaces :(

Comment: Ok, you didnt state what you were using. Did you try [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061775/how-to-call-javascript-from-backingbean-jsf)?

Comment: No. I'll have a look at it. Thanks :)